Having issues with Next.js' fetch API using App Router
Using: Next.js 14+ App Router
I am following this guide: https://wpengine.com/builders/next-js-13-and-wpgraphql-in-headless-wordpress/ to improve my skillset with Next.js/React.js.
My issue is that when I use their code to fetch, I receive a fetch failed error. Though, if I make it a client components and use useEffect and useState, the fetch succeeds and retrieves the data.
Here is what I mean, instead of this code:
const posts = await getPosts();

I use this:
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPosts(){
      const fetchedPosts = await getPosts();
      setData(fetchedPosts);
    }

    fetchPosts()
  }, [posts]);

But I do not want to be using useEffect(()), as I want the server to cache the data fetched as well.
Any thoughts?
Edit: Made an error on which code worked. To reiterate, I do not want to be using useEffect to fetch, I know that sounds incorrect since we don't want our components to fetch each render, but I'm following the guide in the link above. And looking through tutorials online, especially on Next.js docs, they don't use useEffect as well.

It seems like the problem might be with your use of the await keyword inside the useEffect hook.
Dont do that. You can refactor the code like this.
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const posts = await getPosts();
    setPosts(posts);
  };

  fetchPosts();
}, []);


If you're using the app router and react server components, you can mark the component function as async and use the the await right in the root of your component, as long as it isn't a client component.
Try something like this:
const MyComponent = async (myPropStuff: MyPropStuffType) => {
    const posts = await fetch(...)
}

But again, this only works if that component isn't a client component and neither are any of it's parents. That means no useEffect or useState at all.

It is actually in a component of export default async function PostList() {...}. I'm following the guide above.

Can you show some more information in your original post then? Maybe edit it and show the network tab in chrome for the request that's failing, the rest of you component code and maybe the console output as well?

I might have found the issue/solution. Since I am using a local wp site to try to fetch data from, it might not be accessible during Next.js build time. I attempted the original code provided in the guide on a live wp site, and it fetches.

Did you set the NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT env variable?
